# Is there a server/client like VNC that a user can start to then login to a terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

VNC provides a way for a regular user to start a server on a host, then use the corresponding client to connect to the VNC server from another host. I'm looking for a server/client pair that works in a similar way, but only provides simple terminal access rather than access to an X display. This would be similar to telnet or ssh, but the daemon is started by a normal user. Do you know of anything like this? I could write my own, but maybe there's something good out there already.

Comment: You mention ssh. Is there a reason why ssh won't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/344295/is-it-possible-to-run-sshd-as-a-normal-user) to run OpenSSH daemon as a regular user. This will allow a regular user to start their own SSH daemon on their own port with their own configuration file.

> Similar to ssh but the daemon is started by a normal user

---> How about **identical** to `ssh` but the daemon is started by a normal user? Will that work?